# PHP: Extract specific value from string

Tags: php, url

I succesfully read a specific webpage into a variable using:

```
$content=file_get_contents('https://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=82.36.170.89');
```

I need to extract from this page the following data:

```
Country:    United Kingdom
Capital:    London
State:  Camden
City Location:  Hampstead
```

So maybe use 4 variables like:

```
$country="United Kingdom"
$capital="London"
$state="Camden"
$citylocation="Hampstead"
```

The part of the page with the needed data is something like:

```
<tr><th>Country:</th><td> United Kingdom &nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/ip-flags/gb.png' alt='IP Location Find In United Kingdom'> (GB)</td></tr><tr><th>Capital:</th><td class='tracking'>London</td></tr><tr><th>State:</th><td class='tracking lessimpt'>Camden</td></tr><tr><th>City Location:</th><td class='vazno'>Hampstead
```

How can I exctract these values?
Thank you
Lucas

Comment: you can try this one https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7XVwV32pR4/

Comment: @SafakCiplak If you look at the contents of `$content` you will see that page is a **lot** more complex than the OP is letting on

Comment: Yes, I believe I have to exctract firstly thw row with the needed data, then exctract the values I need... What I don't know is how to extract it

Comment: @LucasRey your code is this one https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TSGRZXkk7P/

Comment: @Safak Ciplak Thank you!! It seems it works great!